# How do you reach level 5 in Heroes of Newerth

Tags: heroes-of-newerth

i recently started playing HON, and see that in order to get verified, you either have to buy any amount of gold, or you need to reach level 5. Now my question is, how do you get to level 5. I have played a couple of matches already, but I have not gained any XP to increase my level. Im still at level 1 and it has not even begun to increase. I have played some hosted matches and some CoOp matches against AI, but nothing. So what do I do to get my level up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to play PvP so you can level up. If you don't, it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

You must play matchmaking matches, only they give XP and silver coins.